# How to disable the auto update feature of a software.?

Tags: software-update, conferencing, developer-tools, live-meeting

For the conference call / meeting , there is a tool name free conference call for desktop (windows 10), the desktop tool works fine with base version, but withe latest version its not working properly. Also, if we uninstall the latest version and do install the initial version, by auto its getting updated to the latest version. Do we have any option / way to disable the auto update feature?

Tool Name - Free Conference Call
working version -FCC V 3.1.7158.1001

Failure version - FCC V 3.2.7308-21af3ea.

Thanks
KSK

Comment: Best to contact the software vendor, and report the issue. They may suggest an interim solution or provide a flag you can set to prevent updates.

Comment: If the software is designed to automatically update itself, and there is no option to disable that behavior, then you would have to be disconnected from the internet when the client is started.  Of course that more than likely is not going to work since it's a tool that is only useful if you are connected to the internet.  So the more likely answer to your question is **you cannot**.

Comment: If you can find the update server's IP, and if it's *not* the same as the IP of the meeting server, just block the update server in the firewall.